# Glassfish SSL installed and works, but upon restart fails

Tags: ssl, glassfish

I have installed my SSL certificates on Glassfish 3.2 and everything works as it is supposed to.
I am facing a very strange problem: On server restart, SSL does not work, but when I click the **save button** on the web interface of the listener, **without making any further changes**, it immediately starts working!!!!

Any ideas???

PS. All passwords for the certificates and the master-password are the same.

Comment: please share configurations/changes you have made or the steps you have followed. This will help other other members to help you better.

Comment: Besides this being a very old version of Glassfish and you probably should do an update: probably the network listener is somehow disabled or in an incorrect state and when you press "save" it probably writes back the defaults to the configuration file and it starts working again. Wild guess. You could verify that looking at the domain.xml before and after you press "save".

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.... but domain.xml before and after the save are identical...

Comment: OK, but do you see any messages in the log file when you press "save". E.g. something along the lines of "network listener enabled" or the like?